# how to avoid sending messages to actors not created yet?

Tags: akka

I hope it is ok to ask this. I am using akka and have two actors, where one is initiated/created fast and the other much slower. The rapidly created one asks the other for something (ask-pattern), and the message is sent to dead letters since the other is not initiated yet. What is the preferred way of making an actor waiting with sending it´s message? I am not so eager to make an actor sleep or something without knowing there is no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the functionality `become()/unbecome()` Akka provides for Actors. I am assuming in the following code that the `slowActor` gets created by the `fastActor`. The trick here is that the `fastActor` will have two behaviors: one for when the `slowActor` is getting initiated and the other for when it's ready to do some work. When `slowActor` is ready, it will send a message to the `fastActor` to advertise that is able to receive messages. `fastActor` will be `watch`ing `slowActor` and if it gets terminated, it will change its behavior again. What to do next would be up to your solution.

Here is a mock code as a guide (I have not compiled the code and it might contain some errors):

```
case object Ready
case object DoWork
case object WorkDone

class FastActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

    val slowActor = context.actorOf(SlowActor.props)
    context.watch(slowActor)

    def receive = slowActorNotReadyBehavior

    def slowActorNotReadyBehavior = {
        case DoWork => log.warning("Slow actor in not ready, I am sorry...")
        case Ready => context.become(slowActorReadyBehavior)
    }

    def slowActorReadyBehavior = {
        case DoWork => (slowActor ? DoWork).pipeTo(self)
        case Terminated(ref) => 
            log.error("Slow actor terminated")
            context.unbecome()
            //... do something with slowActor
    }
}

class SlowActor extends Actor {

    override def preStart = {
        context.parent ! Ready
    }

    def receive = {
        case DoWork =>
            //do something
            sender ! WorkDone
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. It might be interesting, but the slow actor is a sibling of the fast actor as of now.